# Need a python script for xml

Tags: python, xml, svg

I am new to python and need a simple script to add/change an attribute in an svg file. I need the attribute 'fill=' added to the path element to add color to layers in the svg file. The script should parse the file, find the path element and if the attribute 'fill=' does not exist add it, if it does exist change its value to 'fill="black"'. Below is a what the xml will look like.

```
<g id="kommuner" class="kommun">
   <path fill="url(#grad1)" id="2521" class="k2521" d="m 263.938,84.75 0.875,0.312 -0.625,2.5 z" />
   <path id="2510" class="k2510" d="m 188.063,100.875 5.375,3.812 1.875,4.25 9.437,6.313 6,3.125 6.938,5.062 7,15.188 -4.938,-3.688 -5,1.938 -6.25,16.062 -2.75,4.5 -3.062,-0.875 -0.313,-1.312 -1.562,-0.813 -0 z" />
   <path fill="red" id="2513" class="k2513" d="m 254,118 1.25,-0.438 2.438,10.625 -0.125,1.563 1.25,0.75 0.625,1.25 -0.688,1.562 1.25,1.438 1.125,2.812 0.063,3.563 -4.375,0.187 -0.688,1.313 -1.25,-0.25 0.25 z" />
   <path id="2514" class="k2514" d="m 255.813,158.5 3.625,1.375 2.062,1.75 0.813,-3.688 0.75,-1.375 1.25,0.5 2.937,0.938 0.813,-2.188 2.187,1 -0.437,-3.625 -5.813,-7.437 -2.75,-2.125 -0.062,-2.5 -4.375,0.187 z" />
   <path id="2518" class="k2518" d="m 269.25,141.625 1.063,0.875 1.25,-1 -0.25 z" />
</g>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to learn the ElementTree XML API:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html